# "Не/ни фига" в значении "ничего подобного"

Tags: грамотная-речь, не-или-ни

Как правильно? Возьмём, например, такой диалог:

— Да ты каждый день туда ходишь.
— Да *не/ни* фига (подобного).

У меня "н**е** фига" (если допустить такое написание) перекликается с "нет" *(да не фига — да нет),* а "н**и** фига" воспринимается как одно отрицание с подразумевающимся вторым. А второго как раз вроде б то и нету в нашем случае!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я считаю, что правильно **ни фига, ни фига подобного.**

Из книги "Вопросы культуры речи. Выпуск XI":
[**фиг**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=5uNTDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124&dq=%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0,%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3,%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0,%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83.&source=bl&ots=Hza-TQ5mg_&sig=ACfU3U03T_8xEzrbmXK0Zabbu6m01LhACA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjb_535lbboAhVhmYsKHYRNB3EQ6AEwB3oECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83.&f=false): *до фига, на фиг, на фига, **ни фига**, по фигу.*

*За последние пять лет хоть что-то в ментовке изменилось? **Да ни фига*** (А. Кивинов).

*Только потому, что мы с вами завели плохое регулирование поведения человека в обществе? **Да ни фига подобного!*** (С. Данилова)

> И вот люди объединялись в государство, а места пустого вокруг было до фига, и никому они жить не мешали, и им никто не мешал. Было хорошо. Казалось бы.
>   **Ан ни фига подобного.**
>   (М. Веллер. Все о жизни)

Дополнение

**Ни фига** — это и есть собственно **ничего** (и нет разницы — имеется рядом с ним отрицание или не имеется): ни фига подобного = ничего подобного; ни фига нет = ничего нет; ни фига себе = ничего себе.

В словаре Ожегова:
[**фиг**](https://how-to-all.com/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5:%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0), -а, м. (прост.). То же, что кукиш.
Ни фига — совсем ничего, ни черта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Римма! Дело в том, что я тоже всегда склонялся к НИ, особенно в смысле "ничего" (ни фига не понимает), да и в этом значении писал НИ, но перед тем, как задал вопрос, написал НЕ и не возникло ощущения, что надо срочно поправиться. Вот с "подобного" в конце хочется НИ сказать, а без — почему-то и НЕ кажется возможным. Хотелось бы: "считаю, что правильно... **потому-то и потому-то**". Тогда обязательно проголосую за ответ.

Comment: Ну-у... К своему мнению могу добавить мнение орфографического словаря: **ни фига́** _(сниж.)_ http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?ab=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0

Comment: В принципе, убедительно, но мне просто интересно узнать ваши собственные мысли, что интуиция говорит (не только сам выбор, но и какая мотивировка внутренняя).

Comment: А интуиция так и молвит. И еще, конечно, ориентируется на **ни шиша́** _(сниж.)._ http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&ab=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B0 _Судя по приложенным усилиям, лукавый должен был трижды изрубить начальницу в спагетти, однако **ни шиша подобного!** (А. Домовец)_

Comment: У меня просто "не фига" (если допустить такое написание) перекликается с "нет" (да не фига — да нет), а "ни фига" воспринимается как одно отрицание с подразумевающимся вторым. А второго как раз вроде б то и нету! Добавлю это в вопрос.

Comment: Римма, но в моём примере же это не "ничего", а "нет".

Comment: Как же ж?.. Вы ведь сами написали: _“Не/ни фига” в значении **“ничего подобного”.**_

Comment: Действительно, написал. Но тут вот в чём фишка: это означает и "ничего подобного" и "нет", но "ничего" из НП мы не берём отдельно, оно лишь образует устойчивое выражение в данном случае. Ни (не) фига = ничего подобного = ***вовсе нет.***